# Is it correct to call openlog before every syslog call without affecting performance?

Tags: perl, syslog

There are two packages that call Sys::Syslog::openlog with different identities and this is causing the messages to be logged randomly with either identities.

For example: if a script that's import package1 is run ahead of another script that's importing package2, the identity of the later script becomes persistent.

The syslog documentation says to call openlog before syslog but I am wondering if that should be done before every syslog call without affecting performance.

What's the right thing to do?

Comment: Are these packages running in separate processes? Or are you trying to have two ident strings in the same process?

Comment: These are running in separate processes.

Comment: We have an FCGID process that starts and loads multiple modules including CGI modules in one process space and then it forks into multiple child processes where each CGI request is handled by these child processes.

Now as new CGI requests call openlog the identity changes throughout all process space. (this is I think what's happening).

Comment: Well you can't share the handle between different child processes like that, can you? Same applies to any file handle.